# Generating React routes on the fly

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I am currently developing an event management application that allows customers to register for events created by multiple event organisers. The backend API routes look like this:

```
http://my-app.com/eventorganizer1/events/event_id=1/new
http://my-app.com/eventorganizer1/events/event_id=2/new
http://my-app.com/eventorganizer2/events/event_id=1/new
http://my-app.com/eventorganizer3/events/event_id=1/new
```

Instead of explicitly declaring all the routes by the event organiser inside React Router, what strategy can I adopt to generate them on the fly (for example, assuming all the event organisers are stored inside a mongoose model)?r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For posterity, I found the answer to my question.

The idea is to generate 'Links' from mongoose/array/API through something like a map function,then funnel the routes using React-Router and finally, processing these routes through match.params:

```
const EventOrganisers = () => (
  <div>
    <ul>
      {
        eventorganisersAPI.all().map(p => (
          <li key={p.number}>
            <Link to={`/eventorganiser/events/${p.number}`}>{p.name}</Link>
          </li>
        ))
      }
    </ul>
  </div>
)

...

<Route path='/eventorganiser/events/:event_id' component={Event}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to setup a more generic route handler you could add the following route and create a component to process all requests:

> Route path="*" component={RouteHandler} />